# How to render custom syntax in Markdown with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

We're moving a large static site built in Assemble to Gatsby. The neat thing we built was custom syntax in Markdown for non-technical authors. Think of it as a CMS without DB where authors use Github as a tool to edit/approve posts and deploy. Besides the ability to add classes to the Markdown (with markdown-it-attrs), we also added the ability for author to inject components into the markdown which it would get rendered as HTML on the page. This has proven to be a very effective way for collaboration amongst teams. I'll show you an example of an accordion component we built with custom syntax in markdown and its output.

If the author needed to use an accordion on the page, all he/she needed to do was this:

```
:::: accordion

::: accordionPanel For Designers

- [WebAIM Color Contrast Checker](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/ "external"){.ds-link--external}
- [Color Contrast Analyzer (Windows)](https://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/ "external"){.ds-link--external}
{.ds-list}

:::

::: accordionPanel For Developers

- [Chrome Accessibility Tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accessibility-developer-tools "external"){.ds-link--external}
- [Keyboard testing (WebAIM.org)](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/ "external"){.ds-link--external}
- [quail](https://plugins.jquery.com/quail/){.ds-link--external} - jQuery plugin for checking content against accessibility guidelines
- [a11y](https://github.com/addyosmani/a11y "external"){.ds-link--external} - Accessibility audit tooling for the web
{.ds-list}

:::

::::
```

The code above would get rendered as:

```
<ul class="accordion">
  <li id="accordion-panel_For Designers" class="ds-accordion--item accordion--item" data-behavior="toggle">
    <h3>
      <a id="accordion-panel_For Designers--toggle" href="#null" class="accordion--title" aria-label="For Designers
        shows more content
      WebAIM Color Contrast CheckerColor Contrast Analyzer (Windows) - shows more content">
        For Designers
        <span class="h-sr-only a11y-text-toggle">shows more content</span>
      </a>
    </h3>
    <section id="accordion-panel_For Designers--panel" class="accordion--content" tabindex="-1">
      <ul class="ds-list">
        <li>
          <a href="http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/" title="external" class="ds-link--external" aria-label="For Designers - shows more content WebAIM Color Contrast CheckerColor Contrast Analyzer (Windows) - shows more content">
              WebAIM Color Contrast Checker
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/" title="external" class="ds-link--external" aria-label="For Designers - shows more content WebAIM Color Contrast CheckerColor Contrast Analyzer (Windows) - shows more content">
              Color Contrast Analyzer (Windows)
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </section>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

As you can see, we use four colons (::::) as the opening and closing tag for a component, in this case an accordion. The question is how to do this in Gatsby since React renders components in a very different way than Assemble. My team is also learning React as move the site so it's been an interesting challenge. Please, feel free to share ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby now supports this via a library called `rehype-react`. Definitely read through the doc, there are a few gotchas like only supporting lowercase prop names.

- [Official Gatsby doc explaining how-to](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/)
- [Example site using custom components](https://prestonrichey.com/blog/react-in-markdown/)

Answer (score -1):

You can write plugins which operate on the Remark (markdown parser) AST to do custom stuff like this. Check out the source of the various remark plugins in https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/plugins/